# Same logic on UIViewController and UITableViewCell, how to maintain one source code?

Tags: objective-c, refactoring

As the title says, I share the same logic between an UIViewController and an UITableViewCell, which send some info to a server and do some calculus.

I'm having the problem that the replicated code is bigger as time passes but I don't know how to factorize this because the clases are different objects and each function call instance variables.

Which is a good way to re-factorize the code so I don't have to change the same code twice  everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way of refactoring a duplicated code is to make a method out of the common part. An important question is where to put it. When the objects are related, you can put the common code in their common ancestor; when they are not related, you might consider creating a helper class with only class methods, or defining a C-style freestanding function with the body of your method.

In case the objects are unrelated and you need to use their instance variables, there may be an opportunity to extract a common object. Move all common instance variables needed for the duplicated code into the new common object, along with the code that uses these variables. If the variables are also needed in the original classes from which you have extracted the common part, add getters and setters as needed. Create an ivar for the extracted class, and use its properties in place of the instance variables.

Comment: In my case the classes are not related and I use instance variables on the code I want to separate. The helper class would be nice, I thought about that but I think that is not so clean to implement something like that because of the instance variables. That's why I'm asking for some advice. An example would be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by "I use instance variables on the code I want to separate"? If you have variables related to your server calls that you need to display in your table view cell or something, you can expose that information through a property in your server class.

Comment: @clopez Take a look at the edit: if duplicated code uses common ivars, you should be able to extract a common object rather than extracting a common method.

Comment: Thanks, finally I did what you suggested, I created a new object with the instance variables of both objects shared and on the ViewController and tableViewCell and I had to define methods to connect the ivars of this objects with the new class (the ivars were IBOutlets).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate class for the server interaction, and maybe even create a separate class for processing the data from the server if there's a lot of work involved.

According to the [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern that Apple encourages for iOS development, *views* (such as UITableViewCell) should not be doing things like making requests to servers and processing the results. Rather, your *controllers* should do those things and provide the necessary information (i.e. a *model*) to your view.

For example, you might have a `Server` class with methods like `connect` and `sendData`. It can have an accompanying `ServerDelegate` protocol with a method like `server:didReceiveData:` when you receive information from the server. Your view controller can then instantiate a `Server` object and set itself as the delegate, then do your necessary calculations in the delegate method. After it has some information to provide to the cell, you store that information somewhere and then call `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:...]` to update the cell.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it would be better to move out any logic from `UITableViewCell` to inclusive `UIViewController`. Cell should be responsible only for displaying data.